# Install .safariextz from command line

Tags: selenium, ssh, installation, safari-extension

I am running into an issue with MacOS 10.10 and Safari 8.0 where Selenium driver cannot establish connection with SafariDriver. Details in this thread: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=7933. To run tests locally, the workaround is to download Selenium 2.44.0, extract the package, and doubleclick on SafariDriver.safariextz to install. However through SSH connection this does not work. I want to install the SafariDriver.safariextz from command line, before each test run. Any clues on how to install the .safariextz file from command line?

Update: Just verified that every time Safari is started from SSH connection (/Applications/Safari.app/Contents/MacOS/Safari) all the extensions are removed (Safari-> Preferences->Extensions is empty).

Comment: Still haven't found a solution. Extensions disappear after launching Safari through SSH. Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you are on the same machine, AppleScript should work:

```
# this first part might not be needed
osascript -e 'tell application "Safari"
  activate
end tell'

osascript -e 'ignoring application responses
  tell application "Safari"
    open "'"/path/to/SafariDriver.safariextz"'"
    end tell
end ignoring
tell application "System Events"
  tell process "Safari"
    set frontmost to true
      repeat until (exists window 1) and subrole of window 1 is "AXDialog" -- wait until the dialog is displayed.
        delay 1
      end repeat
    click button 1 of front window -- install
  end tell
end tell'
```

If that fails, then you might have to enable access for assistive devices and applications by opening **System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Accessibility** and check the applications you want to allow access (Safari, etc...).

More info: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202866

Jacob Salmela also has created a utility to do this from command line:

http://jacobsalmela.com/os-x-yosemite-enable-access-assistive-devices-command-line/

Answer (score 0):

The following workaround did trick for me:
After the upgrade Safari extensions are part of the keychain, and over SSH the user does not have access to the login keychain. The solution is to grant that access for EACH ssh session.

```
security -v unlock-keychain -p <password> ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain
```

Then opening Safari with the step below should work
    /Applications/Safari.app/Contents/MacOS/Safari

For a 'permanent' solution add a build step, to execute shell script as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
keychain="~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain"
security unlock-keychain -p <password> ${keychain} &>/dev/null

if [ $? -ne 0 ];then
  echo "Cannot open keychain ${keychain}"
  exit 1
fi
```

As explained here http://sap-production.github.io/xcode-maven-plugin/site/howto/HandlingKeychainsInMasterSlaveEnvironment.html.